# Avoid element from jumping back and forth when reaching scroll breakpoint and making "position:sticky"

Tags: javascript

new to JS any optimization tip is welcome.
On my website i display an image on top of a grid and want that image to get on the left of said grid when scrolling down.
when reaching scrolling breakpoint it keeps jumping back and forth as shown in snippet below. I can see it only happens when position:sticky is active ?

```js
                const container = document.getElementById('front-gallery-container');
                const flashbook = document.getElementById('flashbook');
                const grid = document.getElementById('grid');

                function changeCssOnScroll() {
                if (window.scrollY > 100) { 
                container.style.flexDirection = 'row';
                flashbook.style.alignSelf = 'start';
                flashbook.style.position = 'sticky';
                flashbook.style.top = '50%';
                flashbook.style.maxWidth = '30%';
                flashbook.style.marginLeft = '5%';
                flashbook.style.aspectRatio = '5/1';
                grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(2, minmax(120px, 45%))';
                } else {
                container.removeAttribute('style');
                flashbook.removeAttribute('style');
                grid.removeAttribute('style');
                flashbook.style.position = 'relative';
                }
                }

                window.addEventListener('scroll', changeCssOnScroll);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.front-gallery-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5em;
  justify-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#flashbook {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 3em;
  max-width: 50%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  aspect-ratio: 3/1;
  margin-left: calc((30%) / 2); 
  @media (max-width : 480px) {
  max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.grid-image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(120px, 35%));
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    margin-top: 10em;
  }
}

.grid .grid-item:nth-child(2n + 1) img,
.grid .grid-item:nth-child(2n + 1),
.grid img:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  aspect-ratio: 4/4;
  grid-row: span 4;
}
.grid .grid-item:nth-child(2n + 2) img,
.grid .grid-item:nth-child(2n + 2),
.grid img:nth-child(2n + 2) {
  aspect-ratio: 4/5;
  grid-row: span 5;
}
```

```html
<div id='content'>
<div class="front-gallery-container" id="front-gallery-container">

  <img src="https://yakes.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/typo-yakes-flash-book.png" alt="flashbook" class="flashbook" id="flashbook">
  <div class="grid" id="grid">
    <img src="https://www.referenseo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/image-attractive-960x540.jpg" class="grid-image fade-in">
        <img src="https://www.referenseo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/image-attractive-960x540.jpg" class="grid-image fade-in">
        <img src="https://www.referenseo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/image-attractive-960x540.jpg" class="grid-image fade-in">
        <img src="https://www.referenseo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/image-attractive-960x540.jpg" class="grid-image fade-in">
        <img src="https://www.referenseo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/image-attractive-960x540.jpg" class="grid-image fade-in">
        <img src="https://www.referenseo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/image-attractive-960x540.jpg" class="grid-image fade-in">
        <img src="https://www.referenseo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/image-attractive-960x540.jpg" class="grid-image fade-in">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a `console.log(window.scrollY)` at the very beginning of your `changeCssOnScroll` function, before the if condition - and you will see, when you scroll down slowly, that the scrollY resets to 0, after you are doing that quite heavy manipulation of the page content. Not sure if there is a simple solution for that, maybe you'd need to "suspend" the whole function for a while after this. (But unless you had planned to add some sort of animation to this later, so that the whole move will happen a lot smother, I would find this kind of effect way to "janky" to begin with, to be enjoyable.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it unlocked the situation. It's indeed janky i solved the whole situation by just having the image on top duplicated, put out the grid-container.

In the grid container i placed the duplicated image with display:none and change it to display:block when (window.scrollY > window.innerHeight /2)  (might adjust later)